# set error to field in zend form

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have this form in Zend where the user should set up start & end date of something. I'm trying to invalidate the form / field if the end date is behind start date but it's not working. I overwritten the isValid() method and it worked but right now something else it's not working just because the isValid() method is overwritten.

how am i doing things:

```
$req = $this->getRequest();
$form->setAction($req->getRequestUri());

if($req->isPost() && $form->isValid($req->getPost())) {
    $startTime = strtotime(date($form->getValue('live_start')));
    $endTime = strtotime(date($form->getValue('live_end')));
    if($startTime > $endTime){
        $form->live_end->addError("End time shouldn't be earlier than start time !!!");
    }
```

If I use die; inside the if() it will die. So it's guaranteed that that if it's working. I used all kind of methods but it's not working.

Anyone have some ideas why it doesn't?

Comment: You are making some validation logics after calling the form `isValid` method ...

Comment: @php-dev well, my only option is to overwrite the isValid() method again, but i have things that will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to :

- Create a new validator, For example `YouApp_Validate_Date_GreaterThan`
- Attach it to the live_end field.
- Override your form `isValid` method, in such a way

:

```
public function isValid($data)
{
    $this->live_end->getValidator('GreaterThan')->setDate($data['live_start']);
    return parent::isValid($data);
}
```

In your validator implementation, set the Date to compare to as a property to easily set it dynamically `->setDate($yourDate)`

Hope it helps.